# Can't build empty "Visual C++ CLR Library" for x64

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, visual-studio-2012

I've added "Visual C++ CLR" project to my solution. Everything was build with no errors. Then In "Configuration Manager" I've changed "Win32" config to "x64", because I need to compile for x64. And now my project can't be built. I have a lot of errors which I don't know how to fix

```
Error   1   error C2871: 'System' : a namespace with this name does not exist   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   3   1   ACliAdapter
Error   2   error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name    C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   4   1   ACliAdapter
Error   3   error C2871: 'Reflection' : a namespace with this name does not exist   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   4   1   ACliAdapter
Error   4   error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name    C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   5   1   ACliAdapter
Error   5   error C2871: 'CompilerServices' : a namespace with this name does not exist C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   5   1   ACliAdapter
Error   6   error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name    C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   6   1   ACliAdapter
Error   7   error C2871: 'InteropServices' : a namespace with this name does not exist  C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   6   1   ACliAdapter
Error   8   error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name    C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   7   1   ACliAdapter
Error   9   error C2871: 'Permissions' : a namespace with this name does not exist  C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   7   1   ACliAdapter
Error   10  error C2337: 'AssemblyTitleAttribute' : attribute not found C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   14  1   ACliAdapter
Error   11  error C2337: 'AssemblyDescriptionAttribute' : attribute not found   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   15  1   ACliAdapter
Error   12  error C2337: 'AssemblyConfigurationAttribute' : attribute not found C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   16  1   ACliAdapter
Error   13  error C2337: 'AssemblyCompanyAttribute' : attribute not found   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   17  1   ACliAdapter
Error   14  error C2337: 'AssemblyProductAttribute' : attribute not found   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   18  1   ACliAdapter
Error   15  error C2337: 'AssemblyCopyrightAttribute' : attribute not found C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   19  1   ACliAdapter
Error   16  error C2337: 'AssemblyTrademarkAttribute' : attribute not found C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   20  1   ACliAdapter
Error   17  error C2337: 'AssemblyCultureAttribute' : attribute not found   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   21  1   ACliAdapter
Error   18  error C2337: 'AssemblyVersionAttribute' : attribute not found   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   34  1   ACliAdapter
Error   19  error C2337: 'ComVisible' : attribute not found C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   36  1   ACliAdapter
Error   20  error C2337: 'CLSCompliantAttribute' : attribute not found  C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   38  1   ACliAdapter
Error   21  error C2337: 'SecurityPermission' : attribute not found C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   40  1   ACliAdapter
Error   22  error C2653: 'SecurityAction' : is not a class or namespace name    C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   40  1   ACliAdapter
Error   23  error C2065: 'RequestMinimum' : undeclared identifier   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\ACliAdapter\AssemblyInfo.cpp   40  1   ACliAdapter
Error   24  error C2871: 'System' : a namespace with this name does not exist   c:\oleg\projects\Va.mbclient\Acliadapter\ACliAdapter.h  5   1   ACliAdapter
Error   25  error C2059: syntax error : 'public'    c:\oleg\projects\Va.mbclient\Acliadapter\ACliAdapter.h  9   1   ACliAdapter
Error   26  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\oleg\projects\Va.mbclient\Acliadapter\ACliAdapter.h  10  1   ACliAdapter
Error   27  error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\oleg\projects\Va.mbclient\Acliadapter\ACliAdapter.h  10  1   ACliAdapter
Error   34  The type or namespace name 'ACliAdapter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\Va.MBClient\Program.cs 14  7   Va.MBClient
Error   35  The type or namespace name 'ACliAdapterMain' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\Va.MBClient\Program.cs 28  24  Va.MBClient
Error   36  Metadata file 'C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\Va.MBClient\bin\x64\Debug_TestGate\Va.MBClient.exe' could not be found  C:\Oleg\projects\Va.MBClient\TerminatorConsole2\CSC TerminatorConsole2
```

Why x64 configuration doesn't work in c++-cli project?

**upd** I know think that likely project reference "32-bit" version of System, while I need "64-bit" version. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch your project to `/clr:safe` it will target both 64 & 32 bit machine. Also,
consider that for each new configuration you need to set all your settings again.

Comment: thanks, by some reason new created "x64" configuration was "no clr runtime support". I've enabled clr support and now project almost can be built, i only have one error `error LNK1561: entry point must be defined`

Comment: why? this is class library. win32 version builts fine.

Comment: i see what happened. probaly when creating x64 configuration I was need to copy all settings from Win32!

Comment: Yah, for each new configuration you need to set all your settings again.

Comment: well now my project compiles but it is not connected with "/clr:safe" option. instead when creatin "x64" configuration I have to "copy from Win32"